# sqlite cursor executes only one row in for loop

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm running this code, I can definitely output any column of available rows but when I try to insert new results within the for loop it only inserts the first row then it stops.

The goal here is to sort rows by two different arguments, I do have those news articles that I want sorted by sqltime and then by score.

I tried doing `SELECT Title, Description, URL, IMGLink, Score FROM today ORDER BY Score DESC, sqltime ASC` but only the first argument is executed and the other one is ignored.

I was thinking that creating a separate table would solve the issue; here's the code:

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT Title, Description, URL, IMGLink, Score FROM main"):
    nline = (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO today (Title, Description, URL, IMGLink, Score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (nline))
    conn.commit()
```

And I would simply access `today` table and order it by Score

[This is my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf4gQ.jpg)

Comment: "I want sorted by sqltime and then by score": Then the `ORDER BY` clause should read `ORDER BY sqltime ASC, score DESC` not the other way round.

Comment: What do you mean *only the first argument is executed and the other one is ignored*? In `ORDER BY` clause? Please post data and show us.

Comment: @sticky-bit still not working

Comment: @parfait I added an img to my post

Comment: For future questions/fyi, images are one of the quickest ways to stop the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify matters by using a single execution using INSERT INTO table SELECT.....;

e.g. the SQL could be :-

```
INSERT INTO today (Title,Description,URL,IMGLink,Score) SELECT Title, Description, URL, IMGLink, Score FROM main ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

You wouldn't need a Cursor, although you may wish to obtain the result (the number of affected rows i.e. inserts).

You may wish to have a look at :-

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - INSERT - 2. INSERT INTO table SELECT ...;](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

Committing your insert might be causing the select cursor to reset as described in this bug report: https://bugs.python.org/issue23129
Try building a list of results inside the loop, and then inserting them outside of the loop. This will also help with performance